# How do I set the contents of a Metal Buffer as a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, objective-c, multidimensional-array, metal

I need to set the contents of a Metal Buffer as a 2D array and I have the following Objective C code:

```
- (void) fillBuffer: (id<MTLBuffer>) buffer input: (UInt8**) inputData internalSize: (unsigned long int) size {
    UInt8** ptr = (UInt8**)buffer.contents;
    for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < size; b++) {
            ptr[a][b] = inputData[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following run-time error when I attempt to set the contents of a `MTLBuffer` as a 2D array using the above code:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

What is the correct way to achieve this? I know that the 2D array will always be 256 elements long and each element of the 2D array has a different size determined by the `size` argument.

Answer (score 1):

`UInt8** ptr = (UInt8**)buffer.contents;`

this cast implies that `contents` holds an array of pointers, which is not true. `MTLBuffer` is a contiguous chunk of memory, it's "1D".

There are still ways to lay out 2D or 3D or any other-D arrays in a linear chunk of memory. In this case, you can lay out your array linearly, column- or  row-wise.

To do it row wise, do this instead:

```
- (void) fillBuffer: (id<MTLBuffer>) buffer input: (UInt8**) inputData internalSize: (unsigned long int) size {
    UInt8* ptr = (UInt8*)buffer.contents;
    for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < size; b++) {
            ptr[a * size + b] = inputData[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

And to use this, you would also need to repeat this access pattern in the shaders.

Comment: When I use your code, I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10fbde000)`.

Comment: This is just an example of how to turn a 2D grid of indices into one linear index. You still have to make sure `MTLBuffer` is big enough and all that. Check what index fails and what's the size of the `MTLBuffer` you are passing to the function.

Comment: is there a way that I can save the data as a 2D array in the buffer rather than saving it in a 1D format?

Comment: I mean, there is, but it is a bad idea to do it just to get an `array[i][j]` syntax. In C++, 2D array is basically an array of pointers to arrays. You can do the same thing with argument buffers in Metal. You can create a "top level" Metal buffer (this is going to hold the pointer to pointers array) and a "second level" Metal buffer per each row (each of these buffers is gonna hold the elements of the row). Then you can write out those `MTLBuffer`s into the top level `MTLBuffer` using `MTLArgumentEncoder`, but as I said, it's just a bad idea. This takes more effort and offers less performance.

Comment: What are you trying to do?